# Using NSLayoutConstraint to adjust views when rotating screen

Tags: swift

I'd like to my display to look like this in portrait and landscape.  I want:

`v1` height = 90

`v3` height = 182

`v4` height = 156

`v2`'s height will vary to fill downward to the bottom of the screen.

How can I do this using `NSLayoutConstraint`s?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could set contraints for both modes as you whish, and activate/desactivate them in the correspding mode.

Answer (score 0):

I Don't realy get what you mean by that but you can block the view so it will never rotate or if you want your blocs to be on one column maybe add a bigger with to your blocs or editate the left and right constrainst.